# How to set ASP.NET start page programatically in VS2008

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2008, ide, settings

In Visual Studio 2008, where is the "Start Page" setting stored for an ASP.NET web site? I am building an add-in and want to be able to switch the startup page for debugging to one of several values. I tried setting the start page to a random string, exited and reloaded the solution to make sure it was persisted, then searched every file in the source tree including hidden/system, and searched the registry for the string, but it is no available.

Comment: I posted this yesterday. Today I had a message about someone "fixing the grammar". Look at the last sentence ending. It ends with "but it is no available". THAT IS INCORRECT! My sentence ended with "to no avail" which means that I was not successful. If you are going to be picky about grammar, at LEAST GET SOMEONE WHO IS QUALIFIED to check grammar! Geeeez!